# Handling back button with fragments and activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an "activity A" that launches two fragments, with the home button being part of the activity A, and when the back button is pressed from the createFragment it should go back to the activity before activity A, which it does fine with the finish() method but when I have the second fragment, followersFragment which is added ontop of createFragment and hides createFragment (because I do not want the information being lost in the create), then I hit the back button and it switches back to the create fragment but then when I hit the back button from createFragment it does not go back to activity A anymore and does nothing... no error...

This is my code on the activity that holds the fragments(not activity A):

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // lets user travel back to where they came from
            case android.R.id.home:
                if(displayShown == 1) {

                    displayView(2, 0);
                } else {

                }
                return true;

private void displayView(int i, int position) {

        Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "display view called " +position);
        boolean createPost = true;
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                //avoid recreating createPostFragment if already created because all data will be erased
                if(createPostFragment == null){
                    createPost = false;
                    Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "fragment create DOES NOT EXIST ");
                    createPostFragment = new CreatePostFragment();
                }



                fragment = createPostFragment;
                break;
            case 1:
                followerFragment = new FollowerFragment();
                fragment = followerFragment;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            trans = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


            //if createpostfrag already created just show
            if (createPost && position == 0) {
                trans.remove(followerFragment);
                trans.show(createPostFragment);
                trans.commit();


                //hide createpostfrag so we can reuse
            } else {
                if(position == 1) {
                    Bundle extraData = new Bundle();
                    extraData.putInt("follow", i);
                    fragment.setArguments(extraData);

                    trans.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment, null).commit();
                    trans.hide(createPostFragment);
                }

                if(position == 0) {

                    trans.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment, "keepAlive").commit();
                }

            }

        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "Error in creating fragment or no fragment needed");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think your code design uses too much transaction remove/show with add/hide. And further complications with some if/else blocks. I would suggest to simplify the code design. I see many posts with Transaction manipulations, that the code become unsolvable and nobody in SO can help. Just my humble opinion, for your sake.

Comment: find and replace this `trans.hide(createPostFragment);trans.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment, null).commit(); and see if it helps
                    `

Comment: Hey Elltz what do you mean by find and replace, switch the order? and the original android how would I simplify it then....